# std::filesystem::file_time_type from time_t - how?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20

I want to create a `std::filesystem::file_time_type` from a `std::time_t` and I can't figure out how.

Example:

```
time_t t = 1337;
std::filesystem::file_time_type ft = ...; //how?
```

Ideally I would like this to work with c++17 but I'll take a c++20 solution too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it in two steps:

1. `time_t` to `system_clock::time_point` via [`std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/from_time_t)
2. `system_clock::time_point` to `file_clock::time_point` via [`std::chrono::clock_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/clock_cast)

Altogether:

```cpp
auto from_time_t_to_file_clock(std::time_t tt) {
    auto st = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(tt);
    return std::chrono::clock_cast<std::chrono::file_clock>(st);
}
```

There is an optional function `std::chrono::file_clock::from_sys` that you can use instead for step 2, but it's optional (there might be a `from_utc` instead), and the `clock_cast` will just do the right thing anyway, so might as well just use it.